# Visual Studio - comment out each line of XML

Tags: xml, visual-studio, comments

When editing an XML file in Visual Studio, I can use the shortcut Ctrl-K Ctrl-C to comment out a region of XML:

```
  <!--<Person>Tom</Person>
  <Person>Dick</Person>
  <Person>Harry</Person>-->
```

However I would like each line to be commented out individually, like so:

```
  <!--<Person>Tom</Person>-->
  <!--<Person>Dick</Person>-->
  <!--<Person>Harry</Person>-->
```

Is there a setting which will allow me to do this, or an existing Extension, or will I have to write my own macro?

Answer (score 3):

[Resharper allows both edits:](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)

- Edit with line comment
- Edit with block comment

Answer (score 0):

Just select the line/lines you want to comment and use Ctrl+ k + c in visual studio. It will comment the block in an XML file.